# Docker: How to give root permissions for the local user?

Tags: docker, jenkins, sudo, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running a build in Docker like this:

```
docker run --user $(id -u):$(id -g) --rm --network=host -v `pwd`:${SRC_MOUNT_DIR} my-image:latest my-build-script.sh
```

I'm setting the local user with `--user` in order to avoid root-owned files appearing in my home dir.

Now, the problem is that I'd need to use `sudo apt install` in my build script to install some dependencies from some other builds, but that would require root.

How could I arrange this? I guess it's not possible to make `sudo` work without password for all possible users..?

Comment: How come you are adding dependencies into your running container? This seems like the sort of thing you do when you build the container image.

Comment: We are developing a library and then there are "customer projects" that are using that library. I'm installing the library as a Deb-archive. Of course all other system dependencies are in the container. Does this make any sense..?

Comment: You might be right that this is an anti-pattern. I still wouldn't like to build a new container image on every commit. Now there's only a single container image that only contains the development tools.

Comment: It does sound like the wrong way to go, but maybe someone will point out a way.

Comment: If you’re using the host filesystem, network, and user ID space, Docker isn’t really providing you with very much isolation.  Can you work directly on the host?  Building a new image per commit is pretty typical Docker practice.

Comment: That is what comes to mind, bulld an image per customer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user inside your container can run `sudo apt install ...` then you may as well run everything in the container as root since any attack could just `sudo ...` any of the attack code. Instead:

- Consider whether you need to `apt install` inside the container, or if you can do that in your image. It would be much better to have binaries installed inside the image and deploy those instead of reinstalling the application every time you run the container.
- If you have a use case that requires root on startup, then start your container as root, and then drop to the user after finishing those root steps. Tools like `gosu` are well designed for this. For an example of an entrypoint that does this, I have a docker-base image with an [entrypoint script](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base/blob/master/bin/entrypointd.sh) that adds `gosu` and runs the CMD with an `exec` to avoid `/bin/sh` as pid 1 (this helps with signal handling).

Gosu can be found at: https://github.com/tianon/gosu